# Why is Android virtual device too slow?

Tags: eclipse, performance, android-emulator

I just downloaded adt-bundle from the android developper's site to give it a try. problems begun when i hited the "run" button: The  Android virtual device or "avd" is horribly slow. I have a pretty decent machine (core i7 & 16go of ram). Aren't they aware of that? i mean it has been several years that people develop for android, how did they manage to do that?

Comment: Golden advice: the simulator is a lie. Develop and test using the real device.

Comment: I can attest to this, we develop for Android at our work and it is well known that simulator is beyond hope.

Comment: Well, iphone emulator is pretty good. there are thousands and thousands of developper for android, no one managed to create a decent one?

Comment: @maroxe Irrelevant, Google is the creator of the emulators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iphone apps running on the **iphone emulator** are compiled for the native processor on the mac, and those only simulate the iphone not the actual processor.

The **normal android emulator** also simulates the processor of the phone which makes it quite slow in comparison.

You could try out the **x86 emulator** that runs natively on your PC' x86 CPU instead of emulating the CPU on the phone. That a look [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/configuring_the_x86_emulator).

Comment: This provides the correct information, but, wanted to point out that the AVD is not an emulator. It is actually running like an Android Device (hence, Android Virtual Device). This is, indeed, why it runs so slow. Highly recommend on getting hardware to test against as others have suggested in above comments.

Comment: There is an emulator called Genymotion, now. I think that one hasn't been around, when this answer was posted. It runs pretty fast and so far I'm very satisfied with it: http://www.genymotion.com/