# few questions about android development

Tags: android, eclipse, development-environment

Hey I've recently rooted my first phone (didn't go as smooth as i'd like it to but the phone works) Anyway, I was thinking that i might learn to develop android apps. The thing is I have a few question which i wasn't able to find answers for or they didn't help me completely.

I downloaded ADT bundle from official android developers website (basically eclipse with the plugins preinstalled, am i right).

The first problem i encountered was that the emulator was so unbelievably slow,i know it's not only my issue and that emulator is slow in general, but I wasn't expecting this. My first app the incredible Hello World app which should take user input and (probably) print it out crashed when i tried to submit the text, though that probably wasn't the fault of emulator but rather problem with my settings (seriously i had to import a lot of stuff just do a simple hello world app) So, let's get to the first question itself. Is there a way to somehow run my app on my phone/tablet (nexus 7 II) in real time? Or besides emulator and copying the app on the device there's no other option?

My second question isn't that much android orientated, but here it goes: This year we are going to learn java at school and i was thinking if i could use ADT bundle from android developers as a regular eclipse if I choose java project instead of android project. Or is it better to use separate eclipse? if so, how do i set those IDEs so that they won't interfere with one and another. It it just a matter of setting different workspaces?

The third question is: Resources. What are some good resources for developing android Apps for beginners. I do have some programming knowledge but it's lather low, i do understand basic concepts, I did use java for really basic stuff but nothing serious. What books/video tutorials or any other resources would  you recommend?

Comment: Regarding slow emulator, take a look at this question: [Why is Android virtual device too slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806828/why-is-android-virtual-device-too-slow/18807239#18807239)

Comment: You get better answers if you post a new "question" for each question you have. That way you can also use a meaningful title.

Comment: Will do, next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good to know that, you are interested in android development. You are right about the android emulator. Its a bit slow. It would be advisable to upgrade you system RAM, if you want to continue use the emulator; though I personally use my device(mobile Samsung Galaxy R) for development purpose.(Its way better than using the emulator). In order to do so, you need to activate the USB debugging option of your phone. [This would probably be helpful!](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/)

As for your second question. I would recommend you to make a Separate Workspace; so that you don't mix stuffs up.

Regards
  -Sathya

Comment: +1 @Sathya for the "This would be helpful" article.